# How to make a working delete/update button per row in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on an admin-page for my website.
So far I can  get the title of my project out of the database and show it on my admin-page. I have multiple titles on my project page, but I want a delete and update button for every title and when I click on one of those buttons I want to delete or edit that specific title.
This is my code so far:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM projects");

if($result->num_rows != 0) {

while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $title_ = $rows["Title"];

    $projects[] = "<div class='row'>
        <div class='project'>
            <input type='text' class='form-control title' value='$title_'/>
            <button type='button' class='btn' name='updateProject'>Save Changes</button>
            <button type='button' class='btn' name='deleteProject'>Delete Project</button>
        </div>

    </div>";
}
}
```

All the titles are in `$projects[]`, and for every `$project` in the database the title gets placed in an `<input>` and for every `$project` it adds 2 buttons (delete and edit).
Does anyone know how I can make those button work per title? So if I click on the delete button of a specific title, I only want to delete that specific title.

Answer (score 1):

*I assuming you meant `do that with ajax` (and thus - with jQuery)*

First, you must supply that project div with project id:

```
$projectID = $rows["ID"];
```

Second, put that ID in html:

```
<div class='project' data-id="$projectID">
        <input type='text' class='form-control title' value='$title_'/>
        <button type='button' class='btn' name='update'>Save Changes</button>
        <button type='button' class='btn' name='delete'>Delete Project</button>
</div>
```

Third, add corresponding script:

```
$('.project [name=update]').click(function () {
    var div = $($(this).parents('.project').first());
    var id = div.data("id");
    var title = div.find('input.title').val();
    $.post('/.../.../script-that-will-process-request.php'{
        project: id,
        title: title,
    }).success(function (r) {
       if (r.response == "ok") {
          alert("Updated!");
       }
    });
});
$('.project [name=delete]').click(function () {
    var div = $($(this).parents('.project').first());
    var id = div.data("id");
    $.post('/.../.../script-that-will-process-request.php'{
        project: id,
        delete: true,
    }).success(function (r) {
       if (r.response == "ok") {
          alert("Deleted!");
       }
    });
});
```

Fourth, add request processing script (that `/.../.../script-that-will-process-request.php` part):

```
$result = ["error" => "unknown action"];
$id = inval($_POST['project']);
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $db->query('delete from projects where ID = ' . $id); // or smth like that
    $result = ["response" => "ok"];        
} else if (isset($_POST['title'])) {
    $title = escape_sql($_POST['title']);
    $db->query("update projects set Title = '$title' where ID = $id"); // or smth like that
    $result = ["response" => "ok"];        
}

die(json_encode($result);
```

Fifth, supply html with no-js fallback:

```
<div class='project' data-id="$projectID">
    <form action="/.../.../script-that-will-process-request.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="project" value="$projectID" />
        <input type='text' class='form-control title' value='$title_'/>
        <input type="submit" class='btn' name='update'>Save Changes
    </form>
    <form action="/.../.../script-that-will-process-request.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="project" value="$projectID" />
        <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="1" />
        <input type="submit" class='btn' name='delete'>Delete Project
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$title_ = $rows["Title"];
$id = $rows["id"] // or whatever your table id is called in the db

$projects[] = "<div class='row'>
    <div class='project'>
        <input type='text' class='form-control title' value='$title_'/>
        <a type='button' href='/path/to/page/update?id='".$id."' class='btn' name='updateProject'>Save Changes</a>
        <a type='button' href='/path/to/page/delte?id='".$id."' class='btn' name='deleteProject'>Delete Project</a>
    </div>

</div>";
```

}

Then create the scripts for update and delete on those pages. Thre are nice ways to do this, but I think this should get you started and then you can improve once you have it working.

Comment: and how would the query to delete/edit that specific project look like?

Comment: "DELETE FROM projects WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."';"   update will be similar.

Comment: So far I've got the delete button working(thank you), but I have a feeling that the edit button isn't exactly the same because the form where I want to edit my project is in admin.php and when I click the edit button it goes to edit.php, and then it should update the old data with the new data, but the new data is in admin.php, and the update function is in edit.php so I can't really update it in edit.php

Comment: well then your update buttons href property should point to the admin page: href="path/to/admin.php?id={your id}" in the admin page you then retrieve all data for that id "SLECT * FROM projects WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']"';" and populate your form before loading it. Do not forget to add a hidden input that contains the project id to the form so that you know which DB row to update after form submission.